# Opposite word of Nomophobia

Tags: word-request

Since I don't use my mobile phone much like others. I want to mention me as in one word "this kind of person" who don't care much about mobile phones or attending calls. I know the word Nomophobia means fear of being without phone. But I couldn't find any opposite word for the word Nomophobia.

Comment: Is there a name for such a person in your own language? One who does not suffer emotional distress when they are without a mobile phone?

Comment: My native language is one of a very old language that doesn't change much with the time like other languages do. Until now, we don't have any word like Nomophobia, but english has. That is why I'm asking this doubt. All i want is to know is there any word to mention someone who don't have much interest in gadgets, it would be great to know. Like teetotaller for nonsmokers or nondrinking persons. If there is nothing like that, leave it, i will take that as no words available.

Comment: Teetotalers *refuse* to drink alcoholic beverages. They *abstain*, but you're not asking about someone who refuses to use mobile phones; you have described the person as someone who doesn't really care about mobile phones. To them, it's just another device, not something they must have, the lack of which makes them feel anxious or distressed in some way.

Comment: So no word. Ok, no problem, thanks for your comment. My intention was not to ask a stupid question here, but i was just curious to know is there any word really available.

Comment: It's not a stupid question, but it's unlikely that there will be a specific name for such a *normal* person, who doesn't have the phobia of being without their mobile, who treats it not as a necessity for emotional well-being but as a convenience. It's like asking if there's a word for a person who is not a drug addict, for "the opposite of 'addict' ".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Nomophobia" is essentially a joke word, made up in about 2008. It is not known by most speakers. It has not made it into most dictionaries (http://www.dictionary.com/misspelling?term=nomophobia) It is not considered a distinct medical condition by psychiatrists.

English doesn't have an authority that can decide on what is a word. In about 2008 someone made a joke, and a few other people have picked it up. However, you should not treat "nomophobia" as part of standard English.

The pattern "...phobia" is very productive. One can form lots of words by adding "phobia". The words created can be serious (claustrophobia - the fear of enclosed spaces) or jokey (Hippopotomonstrosesquippedaliophobia - the fear of long words) and new "phobias" are being invented all the time. Most of these words are used once and then forgotten.

There is also no standard term for "not being upset about not having a phone". Instead just explain. "I'm relaxed about not having my phone"

Answer (score 3):

Typically the opposite of any phobia would be a *Philia* - a *fondness* for something. In this case it would be a Nomophilia. A fondness of mobile phones and attending calls.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I think there is no word like Nomophilia.

Comment: Nomophobia is a recently made up word (a portmanteau of no + mobile + phobia) so there's no reason you can't also use the corresponding philia.  The meaning would be a fondness for not having a mobile phone.

You would probably have to explain it to people though, as nomophobia is not a commonly used word yet.

Comment: @ssav I'd guess it is not only not commonly used yet, but never will be. But whatever. :-)

Comment: You might as well say you're "nomofine", really--nomophilia would be that you love being without a phone, I think what you're trying to say is that you're completely at peace without it but not necessarily seeking that condition.  As people have said, it's a made up set of words anyway, you might as well have fun with it.